# SqlAlchemy join on tables with no foreign keys

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have two tables in SqlAlchemy

```
class T1(Record, SqlBase):
    __tablename__ = 'table1'
    __table_args__ = (PrimaryKeyConstraint('column'), {'autoload': True},)

class T2(Record, SqlBase):
    __tablename__ = 'table2'
    __table_args__ = (PrimaryKeyConstraint('column'), {'autoload': True},)
```

I want to join the two tables on some common column

```
session.query(T1).join(session.query(T2), T1.column == T2.column)
```

But I'm getting an error

```
InvalidRequestError: Could not find a FROM clause to join from.  Tried joining to 
... but got: Can't find any foreign key relationships 
between 'T1' and 'FromGrouping object'. Perhaps you
 meant to convert the right side to a subquery using alias()?
```

How do I fix this problem? There are no foreign keys in either table

Comment: Try `session.query(T1).join(T2, T1.column == T2.column)` instead.

Comment: @van for joins on multiple tables what will be the query?

Comment: @SaifaliKaredia: i am sorry, but i do not understand the question. could you please provide a bit more context.

Comment: @van how can I do inner joins on 3 tables with no foreign keys?

Comment: @SaifaliKaredia: see [`join`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/query.html?highlight=join#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join) documentation. You can specify the JOIN clause explicitly by using `onclause` parameter. Example (from documentation): `q = session.query(User).join(Address, User.id==Address.user_id)
`

Answer (score 3):

Useful [Doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join)

You can  use  join if  both  class having  relationship or  you can write query without join like this

```
session.query(T1).filter(T1.column == T2.column)
```

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/30949766/4050261, there is no need for `both class having relationship`