# Flask SqlAlchemy join two models without foreign key MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I am joining two models without a foreign key:

Models:

```
class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "Users"
    userName = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    lastLogin = db.Column(db.DateTime)

class TimeOff
    __tablename__ = "timeOff"
    timeOffID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    userName = db.Column("userName", db.String,   db.ForeignKey('appUsers.userName')),
    dayWork = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

View:

```
result = db.session.query(models.Users).join(models.TimeOff)
```

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Could not find a FROM clause to join from.
>    Tried joining to but got: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'TimeOff' and 'Users'.

I dont have a foreign key defined in table

Answer (score 17):

You need to tell SQLAlchemy how to join the tables. Try something like this:

```
result = db.session.query(Users).join(TimeOff,Users.userName==TimeOff.userName)
```

Comment: Is this join for unrelated tables?

Comment: This works for unrelated tables. Make sure that your tables are populated when running. Took me a while before I realized that I got no results because my table was unpopulated.

Comment: is there a way extend this syntax for situations where you want to filter one of the two tables before the join?

Comment: But how to access `TimeOff` 's attribute ?

Comment: @Mithril - I think I figured it out, you can do `user, time_off = db.session.query(Users, TimeOff).join(TimeOff, Users.userName == TimeOff.userName).first()`

Comment: How can you add a specific value from `TimeOff` directly to the `Users` ORM object via a query though? So that `Users.time_off` could be a list of time off entries.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same thing, I would like to be able to do users.time_off

Answer (score 5):

To improve upon @Matt Healy's answer, if you also want to be able to access attributes on the joined object you can do something like:

```
user, timeOff = db.session.query(Users, TimeOff).join(
    TimeOff, Users.userName == TimeOff.userName
).first()
```

Then `timeOff.dayWork` etc. will give the information you need.

Comment: What if there are multiple joins to the TimeOff table?

Comment: At that point I think you would need to use sqlalchemy's `aliased()` -> https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#using-aliases

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, I want to join the two objects so that I can get the `Author` information of the `Posts`, but I don't want to use the architecture-level foreign key design to associate the two tables.here is my codes:

```
class Posts(db.Model):
    id= db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    author_code= db.Column(db.String)
    ...

class Author:
    id= db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name= db.Column(db.String),
    code= db.Column(db.String)
    address= db.Column(db.String)
    ...
```

we can add the code like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class Posts(db.Model):
    id= db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    author_code= db.Column(db.String)
    ...
    # add this line
    author_info = relationship('Author',
                           foreign_keys=[author_code],
                           primaryjoin='Author.code == Posts.author_code')
```

then we can get `author_info` by query like this:

```
post_id = xxx # some id you defined
post = Posts.query.filter_by(id=post_id).one_or_none()

# here you can get `author_info` attributes you want.
print(dir(post),post.author_info)
```

You can learn more about this with link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37809175/14295718),and read the documents [Configuring how Relationship Joins — SQLAlchemy 1.4 Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/join_conditions.html#creating-custom-foreign-conditions)

Answer (score 0):

Its an old post but I had a similar problem

```
result = session.query(models.Users).join(models.TimeOff, models.Users.userName == models.TimeOff.userName).all()
```

with this method, I can reach the features of the first object which is Users but not the TimeOff. I am wondering if it is possible to reach the secondary object's attributes. But I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,
I have 3 tables, And I have the rtf_id which is unique to all three tables, you have to use the select_from keyword which tells the table starting from left.

```
db_data = dbobj.session.query(A, B, C). \
select_from(A).join(B, B.rtf_id == A.rtf_id). \
join(C, C.rtf_id == A.rtf_id).all()
```