# sqlalchemy: create relations but without foreign key constraint in db?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

Since `sqlalchemy.orm.relationship()` already implies the relation, and I do not want to create a constraint in db. What should I do?

Currently I manually remove these constraints after alembic migrations.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Instead of defining "schema" level [`ForeignKey`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.ForeignKey) constraints create a [custom foreign condition](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#creating-custom-foreign-conditions); pass what columns you'd like to use as "foreign keys" and the [`primaryjoin`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.primaryjoin) to [`relationship`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship). You have to manually define the [`primaryjoin`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.primaryjoin) because:

> By default, this value is computed based on the foreign key relationships of the parent and child tables (or association table).

```
In [2]: class A(Base):
   ...:     a_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'a'
   ...:     

In [3]: class C(Base):
   ...:     c_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   ...:     a_id = Column(Integer)
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'c'
   ...:     a = relationship('A', foreign_keys=[a_id],
   ...:                      primaryjoin='A.a_id == C.a_id')
   ...:
```

Foreign keys can also be annotated inline in the [`primaryjoin`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.primaryjoin) using [`foreign()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.foreign):

```
a = relationship('A', primaryjoin='foreign(C.a_id) == A.a_id')
```

You can verify that no `FOREIGN KEY` constraints are emitted for table *c*:

```
In [4]: from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable

In [5]: print(CreateTable(A.__table__))

CREATE TABLE a (
        a_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (a_id)
)



In [6]: print(CreateTable(C.__table__))

CREATE TABLE c (
        c_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        a_id INTEGER, 
        PRIMARY KEY (c_id)
)
```

**Warning:**

Note that without a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint in place on the DB side you can blow your referential integrity to pieces any which way you want. There's a relationship at the ORM/application level, but it cannot be enforced in the DB.

Comment: Note: the key is, no claim of foreign keys on a_id of class C. Arguments of relationship do not seem to affect the schema but only the usage in python.

Comment: Yes, as `relationship` is an ORM concept that helps map the SQL table relationships to the object world, but it does not define them.

Comment: Would that also be the correct way to handle cases where the foreign key rule ties `A.a_id` to `C.a_id` (`a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('C.a_id'), primary_key=True)`?

Comment: A `ForeignKey` defines a constraint in the DB schema. A foreign key constraint helps uphold integrity; it prevents you from inserting `C` with `a_id` that does not exist in `A`, and can also define cascading actions that should take place if an `A` is changed — usually deleted. `relationship` on the other hand defines how objects are related. It can and often does use the DB schema foreign key constraint information to determine what are the key columns, but as seen here it is not strictly required. `relationship` also offers cascading behaviour that define what should happen in Python.

Comment: ...You could define `relationship` properties that for example list only past events or such at the object side of ORM. A simple foreign key constraint alone does not model such, it just enforces key integrity.