# how to perform custom join in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am working with a database that does not have relationships created between tables, and changing schema is not an option for me.

I'm trying to describe in orm how to join two tables without describing Foregin keys. To make make things worst I need a custom `ON` clause in my SQL

Here is my ORM(more or less):

```
class Table1(Base):
   __tablename__ = "table1"
   id1 = Column(String)
   id2 = Column(String)

class Table2(Base):
   __tablename__ = "table2"
   id1 = Column(String)
   id2 = Column(String)
```

### Goal

What I'm trying to create is `relationship` that joins tables like this:

```
.....
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.id1 = Table2.id1 OR Table1.id2 = Table2.id2)
```

### My Attempt

I tried adding following `Table1` but documentation does not explain how is this wrong in terms I can understand:

```
table2 = relationship("Table2", 
                      primaryjoin=or_(foreign(id1) == remote(Table2.id1),
                                      foreign(id2) == remote(Table2.id2)))
```

But when tested this I got wrong SQL query back(I expected to see in SQL the join I described above):

```
str(query(Table1,Table2))
```

> SELECT "table1".id1, "table1".id2, "table2".id1, "table2".id2
>   FROM "table1","table2"

### Note

I don't really undersatnd what `remote` and `foregin` do but I tried to infer from documentation where do they belong, without then I would get error on import saying:

> ArgumentError: Could not locate any relevant foreign key columns for primary join condition *'my full primaryjoin code'* on relationship Table1.other_table.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or are annotated in the join condition with the foreign() annotation.

I don't think that I can use ForeignKey or ForeignKeyContraint because none of my colums are constraned to other table's values.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806625/sqlalchemy-create-relations-but-without-foreign-key-constraint-in-db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
str(query(Table1,Table2))
```

produces a cross join between the 2 tables, as you've observed. This is the expected behaviour. If you want to use inner joins etc., you'll have to be explicit about it:

```
str(query(Table1, Table2).join(Table1.table2))
```

This [joins along the relationship attribute](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join) `table2`. The attribute indicates how this join should happen.

---

Documentation on [`foreign()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.foreign) and [`remote()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.remote) is a bit scattered to my own taste as well, but it is established in ["Adjacency List Relationships"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html#adjacency-list-relationships) and ["Non-relational Comparisons / Materialized Path"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html#non-relational-comparisons-materialized-path) that when foreign and remote annotations are on different sides of the expression (in the ON clause), the relationship is considered to be many-to-one. When they are on the same side or remote is omitted it is considered one-to-many. So your relationship is considered to be many-to-one.

They are just an alternative to [`foreign_keys`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.foreign_keys) and [`remote_side`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.remote_side) parameters.

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong, `relationship` does not create the join in `Query` for me it just describes how to join tables in event I explicitly say I want to?

Comment: That, and the attribute works as a collection of related objects (one-to-many, many-to-many) / reference to a related object (many-to-one) on instances (maps relational model to object model).

Comment: :) Thank you sir, you saved me hours of reasearch today.