# Join without foreign key constraint

Tags: python, sql, join, sqlalchemy

I am trying to perform JOIN between two tables, for which I described the relation with `primaryjoin` attribute. I expected that it will be used to build a query, but it is not, and it is failing with `sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Can't find any foreign key relationships`. Below is the whole code needed to reproduce the error. Please suggest how can I describe my tables and how do I construct a query in a situation when there must be no ForeignKey constraints between these tables:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, MetaData
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, insert
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


METADATA = MetaData()
SQLAlchemyTable = declarative_base(metadata=METADATA)


class Cities(SQLAlchemyTable):
    __tablename__ = 'cities'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)


class Orders(SQLAlchemyTable):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    city_id = Column(Integer, nullable=True)

    # relation creation code is taken from 
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806625/sqlalchemy-create-relations-but-without-foreign-key-constraint-in-db
    city = relationship(
        'Cities',
        foreign_keys=[city_id],
        primaryjoin='Orders.city_id==Cities.id'
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection_string = 'sqlite:///test_join.db'
    db = create_engine(connection_string)
    METADATA.drop_all(db)
    METADATA.create_all(db)
    db.execute(insert(Cities).values([{'id': 1, 'name': 'city_name_1'}]))
    db.execute(insert(Cities).values([{'id': 2, 'name': 'city_name_2'}]))
    db.execute(insert(Orders).values([{'id': 1, 'city_id': 1}]))
    db.execute(insert(Orders).values([{'id': 2, 'city_id': None}]))
    db.execute(insert(Orders).values([{'id': 3, 'city_id': 3}]))
    # i need to get this query:
    print(list(db.execute('SELECT orders.id, orders.city_id FROM orders JOIN cities ON orders.city_id = cities.id WHERE cities.id = 1')))
    # how?
    query = select([Orders]).join(Cities).where(Cities.id == 1)  # not working
    print(query)
    print(list(db.execute(query)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `relationship` is an ORM construct, but you're using the Core to build your query. You have to explicitly define how to join between the two:

```
query = select([Orders]).\
    select_from(join(Orders, Cities, Orders.city_id == Cities.id)).\
    where(Cities.id == 1)
```

Note the use of [`Select.select_from()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.select_from) and [`join()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.join) instead of `select([...]).join()`. If using the [Query API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html) you can define the join based on the relationship:

```
query = session.query(Orders).\
    join(Orders.city).\
    filter(Cities.id == 1)
```

Comment: `session.query` is what i was looking for: a way to use described relationship. Damn, having more than one way to build a query makes sqlalchemy too complicated. I just started to use this library but I already hate it.

Comment: It is in a way 2 libraries in one, and the ORM is built atop Core, so they play along nicely.

Comment: Your previous comment was longer :) Anyway, thanks for the response.

Comment: Yeah, in hindsight it got a bit condescending, so I thought I'd remove it.