# Are foreign keys required when using SQLAlchemy relationships

Tags: sqlalchemy

Reading the following pages, I can see that I can setup relationships between tables using the orm `relationship()` function.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/backref.html#relationships-backref

Using this example:

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    addresses = relationship("Address", backref="user")

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

Do I need to have an explicit `user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))` statement for the `Address` class?

Wont the `relationship(backref=...)` is `User` provide an `Address.user` attribute?

If the `ForeignKey` column is needed in `Address`, then why isn't it needed in `User`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806625/sqlalchemy-create-relations-but-without-foreign-key-constraint-in-db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**
You use **foreign key** in three circumstances:

- You have a multi-key reference to another table.
- You want to name the foreign key reference.
- You want to add additional features, such as cascading deletes.

A fourth reason is also plausible: because local coding standards require the use of an explicit constraint.

**Second:**
According to [SQLAchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/backref.html#relationships-backref) documents

In fact, the **relationship.backref** keyword is `only a common shortcut for placing a second relationship()` onto the Address mapping, including the establishment of an event listener on both sides `which will mirror attribute operations in both directions`.

but it's better use **back_populates** because is explicitly.
we add a .user relationship to Address **explicitly**. On both relationships, the relationship.back_populates `directive tells each relationship about the other one,` indicating that they should establish “bidirectional” behavior between each other.

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    addresses = relationship("Address", back_populates="user")

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))

    user = relationship("User", back_populates="addresses")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mohammad, but unfortunately it doesn't clear things up for me.  First, I chose the backref option because it seemed "easier", but I am happy with doing each side explicitly so it is clear what is happening.  My main misunderstanding is why User doesn't have a foreign key, but Address does.  Is it because (a) an email address can only apply to one user but a user can have multiple email addresses?  (b) I have a reference to the user via the relationship attribute `user`, so is the `user_id` FK absolutely necessary?  Maybe I'm getting confused with python versus SQL/DB?

Comment: (a)exactly. yes, an email address can only apply to one user but a user can have multiple email addresses.


(b) handling FK by database but relationship attribute is in ORM level and handled by SQLAlchemy

Comment: A note about back_populates vs backref: backref is more succinct because you don't need to declare the relation on both classes, but in practice I find it not worth to save this on line. I think back_populates is better, not only because in python culture "Explicit is better than implicit" (Zen of Python), but when you have many models, with a quick glance at its declaration you can see all relationships and their names instead of going over all related models.

Comment: agreed.  It's better that the available attributes are obvious by looking at the class definitions rather than having to magically deduce them from some other class that may have created them.

Comment: To your "first": it is missing "You want to **enforce data integrity in the database**, so you use a foreign key *constraint*."