# SQL-Alchemy: having problems creating relationships without ForeignKeys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Im trying to create relations but without foreign key constraints in db

quite similar to this post:
[sqlalchemy: create relations but without foreign key constraint in db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806625/sqlalchemy-create-relations-but-without-foreign-key-constraint-in-db)

However im trying to do it with classical mapping
and I cant figure out what Im doing wrong with it

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    Table,
    MetaData,
    Column,
    String,

)
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, relationship
from uuid import uuid4


class InspectionRecord:
    def __init__(self, equipment):
        self.equipment = equipment


class InspectedItem:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item


metadata = MetaData()

inspected_items = Table(
    'inspected_items',
    metadata,
    Column('inspection_id', String(50)),
    Column('inspected_item_id', String(50), primary_key=True),
    Column('item', String(50))
)

inspection_records = Table(
    'inspection_records',
    metadata,
    Column('inspection_id', String(50), primary_key=True, default=uuid4),
    Column('equipment', String(50))
)


def start_mappers():
    inspected_items_mapper = mapper(InspectedItem, inspected_items)
    inspection_records_mapper = mapper(InspectionRecord, inspection_records, properties={
        "inspected_items": relationship(inspected_items_mapper,
                                       primaryjoin='foreign(inspected_items.inspection_id) == inspection_records.inspection_id',
                                        uselist=False)}
                                       ) # this is the part where I'm having difficulties with


if __name__ == '__main__':

    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///foo.db')
    metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
    metadata.create_all(engine)
    start_mappers()

    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()

    inspection_record = InspectionRecord(equipment='equipment_01')
    session.add(inspection_record)
```

after so many attempts i even with additional tinkering i only get
this error
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class InspectionRecord->inspection_records, expression '[InspectedItem.inspection_id]' failed to locate a name ("name 'InspectedItem' is not defined")

Any help would be really really really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

got this working:

change to mapper to mapper_registry.map_imperatively

```
def start_mappers():
    inspected_items_mapper = mapper_registry.map_imperatively(InspectedItem, inspected_items)
    inspection_records_mapper = mapper_registry.map_imperatively(InspectionRecord, inspection_records, properties={
        "inspected_items": relationship(InspectedItem,
                                        primaryjoin='foreign(InspectedItem.inspection_id) == InspectionRecord.inspection_id',
                                        uselist=False)}
```